# EXC_BREAKPOINTというエラーが出てしまってどうすればいいのか分かりません。

Tags: swift, iphone

参考書に書いてあるカメラアプリを作ろうと記述通りの手順でコードを書いたつもりです。
コード自体にはエラーは表示されていません。アプリをMacに繋いだ自分のiPhoneで試そうとしたのですが、以下のような表示が出てしまい、iPhone画面が真っ白な状態です。

```
ibswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never:
        0x1002c1184 <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-80]!
        0x1002c1188 <+4>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #16]
        0x1002c118c <+8>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #32]

    .
    .
    .
        0x1002c11f4 <+112>: mov    x4, x8
        0x1002c11f8 <+116>: bl     0x1001b4b80               ; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
    ->  0x1002c11fc <+120>: brk    #0x1
```

上の最後の#0x1の後に"Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x1002c11fc)"が表示されて止まってしまいます。

Swiftを独学で勉強し始めてほんの数日です。基本的な文法もルールもまだ理解していません。試しにアプリを作ってみたくて、本に書いてある通りに操作して作っていました。このサイトを利用するのも初めてです。どうか、この身の程知らずのぺいぺいにご教授お願いします。

追記
コードは

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //プレビュー用のビューとoutlet接続しておく
    @IBOutlet weak var previewView:UIView!
    //インスタンスの作成
    var session = AVCaptureSession()
    var photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    //通知センターを作る
    let notification = NotificationCenter.default

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // セッション実行中ならば中断する
        if session.isRunning {
            return
        }
        //入出力の設定
    setupInputOutput()
        //プレビューレイヤの設定
    setPreviewLayer()
        //セッション開始
    session.startRunning()
        notification.addObserver(self,
                                 selector: #selector(self.changedDeviceOrientation(_:)),
                                 name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    //シャッターボタンで実行する
    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let captureSetting = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        captureSetting.flashMode = .auto
        captureSetting.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
        captureSetting.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = false
        //キャプチャのイメージ処理はデリゲートに任せる
        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: captureSetting, delegate: self)
    }


    //入出力の設定
    func setupInputOutput(){
        //解像度の指定
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto


        //入出力
        do {
            //デバイスの取得
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(
                withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                position: .back)

            //入力元
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if session.canAddInput(input){
                session.addInput(input)
            }else {
                print("セッションに入力を追加できなかった")
                return
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("カメラがない\(error)")
            return
        }

        //入力先
        if session.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
            session.addOutput(photoOutput)
        } else {
            print("セッションに出力をできなかった")
            return
        }
    }

   //プレビューレイヤの設定
    func setPreviewLayer(){
        //プレビューレイヤを作る
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        guard let videoLayer = previewLayer else {
            print("プレビューレイヤーを作れなかった")
            return
        }
        videoLayer.frame = view.bounds
        videoLayer.masksToBounds = true
        videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        //previewViewに追加する
        previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    }

    //デバイスの向きが変わった時に呼び出すメソッド
    func changedDeviceOrientation(_ notification :Notification) {
        // photoOutput.connectionの回転向きをデバイスと合わせる
        if let photoOutputConnection = self.photoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
            case .portrait:
                photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait
            case .portraitUpsideDown:
                photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
            case .landscapeLeft:
                photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
            case .landscapeRight:
                photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

と

```
//  ExtensionViewController.swift
//  avCapturePhoto_simple
//

import Photos

//デリゲート部分を拡張する
extension ViewController:AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    //映像をキャプチャする
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                 didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
                 bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?,
                 error: Error?) {

        //バッファからjpegデータを取り出す
        let photoData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(
            forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer!,
            previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer)

        //  photoDateがnill出ない時UIImageに変換する
        if let data = photoData {
            if let stillImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                //アルバムに追加する
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(stillImage, self, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

です。

```
Autolayout`ViewController.setPreviewLayer() -> ():
    0x10818e7f0 <+0>:    pushq  %rbp
    0x10818e7f1 <+1>:    movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10818e7f4 <+4>:    subq   $0x190, %rsp              ; imm = 0x190 
    0x10818e7fb <+11>:   movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x10818e7ff <+15>:   movq   %rdi, -0x68(%rbp)
    0x10818e803 <+19>:   callq  0x10818ed40               ; type metadata accessor for __ObjC.AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer at ViewController.swift
    0x10818e808 <+24>:   movq   0x68e1(%rip), %rdi        ; (void *)0x000000010aac99a0: swift_isaMask
    0x10818e80f <+31>:   movq   -0x68(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e813 <+35>:   movq   (%rcx), %rdx
    0x10818e816 <+38>:   andq   (%rdi), %rdx
    0x10818e819 <+41>:   movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10818e81c <+44>:   movq   %rax, -0x70(%rbp)
    0x10818e820 <+48>:   callq  *0x68(%rdx)
    0x10818e823 <+51>:   movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10818e826 <+54>:   movq   -0x70(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10818e82a <+58>:   callq  0x10818ece0               ; __ObjC.AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.__allocating_init (session : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.AVCaptureSession>) -> Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer> at ViewController.swift
    0x10818e82f <+63>:   movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10818e832 <+66>:   movq   %rax, -0x78(%rbp)
    0x10818e836 <+70>:   callq  0x10819214c               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x10818e83b <+75>:   movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e83f <+79>:   movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e843 <+83>:   cmpq   $0x0, %rcx
    0x10818e847 <+87>:   movq   %rax, -0x80(%rbp)
    0x10818e84b <+91>:   je     0x10818ec0c               ; <+1052> at ViewController.swift:99
    0x10818e851 <+97>:   movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818e855 <+101>:  movq   %rax, -0x88(%rbp)
    0x10818e85c <+108>:  movq   -0x88(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818e863 <+115>:  movq   %rax, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x10818e867 <+119>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10818e86a <+122>:  movq   %rax, -0x90(%rbp)
    0x10818e871 <+129>:  callq  0x10819214c               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x10818e876 <+134>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818e87d <+141>:  movq   -0x68(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e881 <+145>:  movq   %rdi, -0x98(%rbp)
    0x10818e888 <+152>:  movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10818e88b <+155>:  movq   %rax, -0xa0(%rbp)
    0x10818e892 <+162>:  callq  0x10819214c               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x10818e897 <+167>:  movq   -0x68(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e89b <+171>:  movq   0x8256(%rip), %rsi        ; "view"
    0x10818e8a2 <+178>:  movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10818e8a5 <+181>:  movq   %rax, -0xa8(%rbp)
    0x10818e8ac <+188>:  callq  0x108192134               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x10818e8b1 <+193>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10818e8b4 <+196>:  callq  0x108192152               ; symbol stub for: objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
    0x10818e8b9 <+201>:  movq   %rax, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x10818e8bd <+205>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818e8c1 <+209>:  cmpq   $0x0, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x10818e8c6 <+214>:  jne    0x10818e913               ; <+291> at ViewController.swift:94
    0x10818e8c8 <+216>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818e8cc <+220>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818e8d0 <+224>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818e8d4 <+228>:  leaq   0x4c0f(%rip), %rdi        ; "fatal error"
    0x10818e8db <+235>:  movl   $0xb, %eax
    0x10818e8e0 <+240>:  movl   %eax, %esi
    0x10818e8e2 <+242>:  movl   $0x2, %eax
    0x10818e8e7 <+247>:  leaq   0x4bc2(%rip), %rcx        ; "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
    0x10818e8ee <+254>:  movl   $0x39, %edx
    0x10818e8f3 <+259>:  movl   %edx, %r8d
    0x10818e8f6 <+262>:  xorl   %edx, %edx
    0x10818e8f8 <+264>:  movl   %edx, -0xac(%rbp)
    0x10818e8fe <+270>:  movl   %eax, %edx
    0x10818e900 <+272>:  movl   %eax, %r9d
    0x10818e903 <+275>:  movl   $0x0, (%rsp)
    0x10818e90a <+282>:  callq  0x1081921ca               ; symbol stub for: function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never
    0x10818e90f <+287>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e913 <+291>:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818e917 <+295>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10818e91a <+298>:  movq   %rax, -0xb8(%rbp)
    0x10818e921 <+305>:  callq  0x10819214c               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x10818e926 <+310>:  leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818e92a <+314>:  movq   0x81cf(%rip), %rdx        ; "bounds"
    0x10818e931 <+321>:  movq   -0xb8(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e938 <+328>:  movq   %rcx, %rsi
    0x10818e93b <+331>:  movq   %rax, -0xc0(%rbp)
    0x10818e942 <+338>:  callq  0x108192140               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend_stret
    0x10818e947 <+343>:  leaq   -0x58(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818e94b <+347>:  movsd  -0x38(%rbp), %xmm0        ; xmm0 = mem[0],zero 
    0x10818e950 <+352>:  movsd  -0x30(%rbp), %xmm1        ; xmm1 = mem[0],zero 
    0x10818e955 <+357>:  movsd  -0x28(%rbp), %xmm2        ; xmm2 = mem[0],zero 
    0x10818e95a <+362>:  movsd  -0x20(%rbp), %xmm3        ; xmm3 = mem[0],zero 
    0x10818e95f <+367>:  movq   0x81a2(%rip), %rsi        ; "setFrame:"
    0x10818e966 <+374>:  movsd  %xmm0, -0x58(%rbp)
    0x10818e96b <+379>:  movsd  %xmm1, -0x50(%rbp)
    0x10818e970 <+384>:  movsd  %xmm2, -0x48(%rbp)
    0x10818e975 <+389>:  movsd  %xmm3, -0x40(%rbp)
    0x10818e97a <+394>:  movq   -0x98(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e981 <+401>:  movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10818e984 <+404>:  movq   (%rax), %rcx
    0x10818e987 <+407>:  movq   %rcx, (%rsp)
    0x10818e98b <+411>:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rcx
    0x10818e98f <+415>:  movq   %rcx, 0x8(%rsp)
    0x10818e994 <+420>:  movq   0x10(%rax), %rcx
    0x10818e998 <+424>:  movq   %rcx, 0x10(%rsp)
    0x10818e99d <+429>:  movq   0x18(%rax), %rax
    0x10818e9a1 <+433>:  movq   %rax, 0x18(%rsp)
    0x10818e9a6 <+438>:  callq  0x108192134               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x10818e9ab <+443>:  movq   -0xb8(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818e9b2 <+450>:  callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818e9b7 <+455>:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818e9bb <+459>:  callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818e9c0 <+464>:  movq   -0x68(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818e9c4 <+468>:  callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818e9c9 <+473>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818e9d0 <+480>:  callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818e9d5 <+485>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818e9dc <+492>:  callq  0x10819214c               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x10818e9e1 <+497>:  movl   $0x1, %edx
    0x10818e9e6 <+502>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818e9ed <+509>:  movq   0x811c(%rip), %rsi        ; "setMasksToBounds:"
    0x10818e9f4 <+516>:  movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10818e9f7 <+519>:  movq   %rax, -0xc8(%rbp)
    0x10818e9fe <+526>:  callq  0x108192134               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x10818ea03 <+531>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ea0a <+538>:  callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818ea0f <+543>:  movq   0x660a(%rip), %rax        ; (void *)0x0000000108de8270: AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    0x10818ea16 <+550>:  movq   (%rax), %rdi
    0x10818ea19 <+553>:  callq  0x108192236               ; symbol stub for: static (extension in Foundation):Swift.String._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSString>) -> Swift.String
    0x10818ea1e <+558>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10818ea22 <+562>:  movb   $0x1, %r8b
    0x10818ea25 <+565>:  testb  $0x1, %r8b
    0x10818ea29 <+569>:  movq   %rax, -0xd0(%rbp)
    0x10818ea30 <+576>:  movq   %rdx, -0xd8(%rbp)
    0x10818ea37 <+583>:  movq   %rcx, -0xe0(%rbp)
    0x10818ea3e <+590>:  jne    0x10818ea42               ; <+594> at ViewController.swift:96
    0x10818ea40 <+592>:  jmp    0x10818ea83               ; <+659> at ViewController.swift:96
    0x10818ea42 <+594>:  movq   -0xd0(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ea49 <+601>:  movq   -0xd8(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10818ea50 <+608>:  movq   -0xe0(%rbp), %rdx
    0x10818ea57 <+615>:  callq  0x10819222a               ; symbol stub for: (extension in Foundation):Swift.String._bridgeToObjectiveC () -> __ObjC.NSString
    0x10818ea5c <+620>:  movq   -0xe0(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ea63 <+627>:  movq   %rax, -0xe8(%rbp)
    0x10818ea6a <+634>:  callq  0x108192200               ; symbol stub for: swift_unknownRelease
    0x10818ea6f <+639>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818ea73 <+643>:  movq   -0xe8(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818ea7a <+650>:  movq   %rax, -0xf0(%rbp)
    0x10818ea81 <+657>:  jmp    0x10818ea92               ; <+674> at ViewController.swift:96
    0x10818ea83 <+659>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818ea87 <+663>:  xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x10818ea89 <+665>:  movl   %ecx, %eax
    0x10818ea8b <+667>:  movq   %rax, -0xf0(%rbp)
    0x10818ea92 <+674>:  movq   -0xf0(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818ea99 <+681>:  movq   0x8078(%rip), %rsi        ; "setVideoGravity:"
    0x10818eaa0 <+688>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818eaa7 <+695>:  movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10818eaaa <+698>:  movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x10818eaad <+701>:  movq   %rax, -0xf8(%rbp)
    0x10818eab4 <+708>:  callq  0x108192134               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x10818eab9 <+713>:  movq   -0xf8(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818eac0 <+720>:  callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818eac5 <+725>:  movq   0x6624(%rip), %rax        ; (void *)0x000000010aac99a0: swift_isaMask
    0x10818eacc <+732>:  movq   -0x68(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818ead0 <+736>:  movq   (%rcx), %rdx
    0x10818ead3 <+739>:  andq   (%rax), %rdx
    0x10818ead6 <+742>:  movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10818ead9 <+745>:  callq  *0x50(%rdx)
    0x10818eadc <+748>:  movq   %rax, -0x60(%rbp)
    0x10818eae0 <+752>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818eae4 <+756>:  cmpq   $0x0, -0x60(%rbp)
    0x10818eae9 <+761>:  jne    0x10818eb36               ; <+838> at ViewController.swift:98
    0x10818eaeb <+763>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818eaef <+767>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818eaf3 <+771>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818eaf7 <+775>:  leaq   0x49ec(%rip), %rdi        ; "fatal error"
    0x10818eafe <+782>:  movl   $0xb, %eax
    0x10818eb03 <+787>:  movl   %eax, %esi
    0x10818eb05 <+789>:  movl   $0x2, %eax
    0x10818eb0a <+794>:  leaq   0x499f(%rip), %rcx        ; "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
    0x10818eb11 <+801>:  movl   $0x39, %edx
    0x10818eb16 <+806>:  movl   %edx, %r8d
    0x10818eb19 <+809>:  xorl   %edx, %edx
    0x10818eb1b <+811>:  movl   %edx, -0xfc(%rbp)
    0x10818eb21 <+817>:  movl   %eax, %edx
    0x10818eb23 <+819>:  movl   %eax, %r9d
    0x10818eb26 <+822>:  movl   $0x0, (%rsp)
    0x10818eb2d <+829>:  callq  0x1081921ca               ; symbol stub for: function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never
    0x10818eb32 <+834>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818eb36 <+838>:  movq   -0x60(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818eb3a <+842>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10818eb3d <+845>:  movq   %rax, -0x108(%rbp)
    0x10818eb44 <+852>:  callq  0x10819214c               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x10818eb49 <+857>:  movq   0x7fd0(%rip), %rsi        ; "layer"
    0x10818eb50 <+864>:  movq   -0x108(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818eb57 <+871>:  movq   %rax, -0x110(%rbp)
    0x10818eb5e <+878>:  callq  0x108192134               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x10818eb63 <+883>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10818eb66 <+886>:  callq  0x108192152               ; symbol stub for: objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
    0x10818eb6b <+891>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818eb72 <+898>:  movq   %rax, -0x118(%rbp)
    0x10818eb79 <+905>:  callq  0x10819214c               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x10818eb7e <+910>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10818eb85 <+917>:  movq   0x7f9c(%rip), %rdi        ; "addSublayer:"
    0x10818eb8c <+924>:  movq   -0x118(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818eb93 <+931>:  movq   %rdi, -0x120(%rbp)
    0x10818eb9a <+938>:  movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10818eb9d <+941>:  movq   -0x120(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10818eba4 <+948>:  movq   %rsi, -0x128(%rbp)
    0x10818ebab <+955>:  movq   %rcx, %rsi
    0x10818ebae <+958>:  movq   -0x128(%rbp), %rdx
    0x10818ebb5 <+965>:  movq   %rax, -0x130(%rbp)
    0x10818ebbc <+972>:  callq  0x108192134               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x10818ebc1 <+977>:  movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ebc8 <+984>:  callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818ebcd <+989>:  movq   -0x118(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ebd4 <+996>:  callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818ebd9 <+1001>: movq   -0x108(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ebe0 <+1008>: callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818ebe5 <+1013>: movq   -0x60(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ebe9 <+1017>: callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818ebee <+1022>: movq   -0x90(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ebf5 <+1029>: callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818ebfa <+1034>: movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ebfe <+1038>: callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818ec03 <+1043>: movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818ec07 <+1047>: jmp    0x10818eccc               ; <+1244> at ViewController.swift:99
    0x10818ec0c <+1052>: movl   $0x1, %eax
    0x10818ec11 <+1057>: movl   %eax, %edi
    0x10818ec13 <+1059>: callq  0x10819225a               ; symbol stub for: generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Any> of Swift._allocateUninitializedArray <A> (Builtin.Word) -> (Swift.Array<A>, Builtin.RawPointer)
    0x10818ec18 <+1064>: leaq   0x4851(%rip), %rdi
    0x10818ec1f <+1071>: movl   $0x10, %ecx
    0x10818ec24 <+1076>: movl   %ecx, %esi
    0x10818ec26 <+1078>: movq   0x640b(%rip), %r8         ; (void *)0x000000010aaa1858: type metadata for Swift.String
    0x10818ec2d <+1085>: movq   %r8, 0x18(%rdx)
    0x10818ec31 <+1089>: movq   %rax, -0x138(%rbp)
    0x10818ec38 <+1096>: movq   %rdx, -0x140(%rbp)
    0x10818ec3f <+1103>: callq  0x108192176               ; symbol stub for: Swift.String.init (_builtinUTF16StringLiteral : Builtin.RawPointer, utf16CodeUnitCount : Builtin.Word) -> Swift.String
    0x10818ec44 <+1108>: movq   -0x140(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10818ec4b <+1115>: movq   %rax, (%rsi)
    0x10818ec4e <+1118>: movq   %rdx, 0x8(%rsi)
    0x10818ec52 <+1122>: movq   %rcx, 0x10(%rsi)
    0x10818ec56 <+1126>: callq  0x1081921ac               ; symbol stub for: Swift.(print (Swift.Array<Any>, separator : Swift.String, terminator : Swift.String) -> ()).(default argument 1)
    0x10818ec5b <+1131>: movq   %rax, -0x148(%rbp)
    0x10818ec62 <+1138>: movq   %rdx, -0x150(%rbp)
    0x10818ec69 <+1145>: movq   %rcx, -0x158(%rbp)
    0x10818ec70 <+1152>: callq  0x1081921b2               ; symbol stub for: Swift.(print (Swift.Array<Any>, separator : Swift.String, terminator : Swift.String) -> ()).(default argument 2)
    0x10818ec75 <+1157>: movq   -0x138(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ec7c <+1164>: movq   -0x148(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10818ec83 <+1171>: movq   -0x150(%rbp), %r8
    0x10818ec8a <+1178>: movq   %rdx, -0x160(%rbp)
    0x10818ec91 <+1185>: movq   %r8, %rdx
    0x10818ec94 <+1188>: movq   -0x158(%rbp), %r9
    0x10818ec9b <+1195>: movq   %rcx, -0x168(%rbp)
    0x10818eca2 <+1202>: movq   %r9, %rcx
    0x10818eca5 <+1205>: movq   %rax, %r8
    0x10818eca8 <+1208>: movq   -0x160(%rbp), %r9
    0x10818ecaf <+1215>: movq   -0x168(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818ecb6 <+1222>: movq   %rax, (%rsp)
    0x10818ecba <+1226>: callq  0x1081921a0               ; symbol stub for: Swift.print (Swift.Array<Any>, separator : Swift.String, terminator : Swift.String) -> ()
    0x10818ecbf <+1231>: movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10818ecc3 <+1235>: callq  0x108192146               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x10818ecc8 <+1240>: movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818eccc <+1244>: movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rax
    0x10818ecd0 <+1248>: addq   $0x190, %rsp              ; imm = 0x190 
    0x10818ecd7 <+1255>: popq   %rbp
    0x10818ecd8 <+1256>: retq
```

上のコード（？）の0x10818eb32 <+834>:  movq   -0x78(%rbp), %rcx　の横にThread1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)と表示されてアプリがフリーズしてしまいます。この操作はsimulatorで試みたものです。

Comment: 書かれたコードを提示して頂くことは可能でしょうか？可能であれば質問文に追記をお願いします。

Comment: エラーコードEXC_BREAKPOINTに着目されているようですが、このエラーコードをGoogleで検索すると http://qiita.com/kunichiko/items/8fa9494c659d75e3b9a9 のページがトップに出ます。原因とその突き止め方まで記載されています。コードを提示して頂かないと確かなことは言えませんが、おそらく参考にされている書籍はSwift1.1以前を対象としたものかと思われます。Swift1.1では問題なかった書き方が、Swift1.2以降でエラーとなるように変更されたようです。

Comment: @maot 参考書籍は「詳細Swift3 iPhoneアプリ開発入門ノート」です。

Comment: なるほど。。書籍からすると先に示したURLの問題ではないみたいですね。参考書籍についてもコメントより質問文に記載された方が回答される方の目に入りやすいので、良いと思います。発生しているエラーについても全文記載していただけますか？全文書くと長すぎるようであれば、テキストファイルにして添付等でも良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

こちらはあなたのコードをSingle View Applicationに貼り付けて、Simulatorで実行して実行時エラーが発生したときのXcodeの画面キャプチャーです。

[image: Xcodeのエラー画面]

赤丸は **実行時エラーが発生した時に注目して欲しい場所** を表しています。左側のスタック情報が、どこでエラーが発生したかを表す重要な情報で、中央下のデバッグコンソールにはエラーの原因を表すこれまた重要な情報が表示されていることが多いです。Xcode上で再現可能な実行時エラーに関する質問では(あるいは質問前に原因を探る時には)、この2箇所にチェックを入れ、その内容を質問文に記載するようにしてください。

ちなみにエディター部分はXcodeのメニューで Debug＞Debug Workflow から「Always Show Disassembly」のチェックマークを外しておくと、分かりにくいアセンブラー形式ではなく、Swiftのソースコードが表示されるはずです。

---

さて、今回の件でチェックして欲しいのはデバッグコンソールです。

> **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

と言う表示がありませんか?

もし上の表示が出ていたとしたら、あなたのエラーの原因はこの行にあります。

```
//プレビュー用のビューとoutlet接続しておく
@IBOutlet weak var previewView:UIView!
```

あなたのコードの中で`previewView`は`UIView!`型と宣言されています。これは「`previewView`が`nil`のままで使おうとしたらアプリをクラッシュさせてください」とSwiftに指示したことになります。で、`nil`のまま使ったので、言われた通りにクラッシュした、と言うのが上のXcode画面に示した状態です。

上記の行のコメントに`//プレビュー用のビューとoutlet接続しておく`と記載されていますが、あなたはstoryboard上でUIViewをViewControllerに追加し、そのUIViewをソースコード内の`previewView`と正しく結びつけたでしょうか?

(結びつけを行った後に、あちこち修正すると見かけ上はつながっているはずの結びつきが切れてしまうこともあります。)

とりあえず、上記の **unexpectedly found nil**が当たっているなら、`@IBOutlet`の結びつけがちゃんとできているか再度確認してみてください。(一度消して、再度繋ぎ直したほうが良いかもしれません。)

もし当たっていない場合には、図の中の赤丸で示した部分の情報の質問文への追記をお願いします。

Comment: ご指摘いただいた通り、outlet接続が切れていました。そして、無事にカメラアプリを完成させることができました。ありがとうございます。書き写しただけなのにかなりの達成感があります笑。また、私の拙い文章での質問に丁寧に、エラーに関する質問でのチェック項目、質問の仕方まで教えて頂き感謝しています。最低限のマナーを学ばせていただきました。これからもお世話になります。